# How to make JButton wait One Second?

Tags: java, eclipse, time

OK So I am making a Game Called "Connect Four". What I am Trying do is something like this. So once you press the Button called "Human vs Computer" it should says "Your Game Starts in" "3" (now it should wait One second then it should print) "2" 
(now it should wait One second then it should print) "1".

But when I do it.. it would freeze the "Human Vs Computer Button" which I Don't know why Does it do it. So can you tell me how to fix that issue. This is what I have tried so far.

```
private class humanVsComputerButtonListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {      

  if (event.getSource() == humanVsCom) {

    lblWelcome.setVisible(true);
    playButton.setVisible(false);
    ruleButton.setVisible(true); 
    quitButton.setVisible(true);
    humanVsCom.setVisible(false);
    multiplayer.setVisible(false);
    withTimeLimit.setVisible(false);
    noTimeLimit.setVisible(false);
    ruleButton.setVisible(false);
    quitButton.setVisible(false);
    goBack.setVisible(false);          
    lblGameStarts.setVisible(true);

    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);                        
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }

    lblGameStarts.setVisible(false);          
    lblinThree.setVisible(true); 

    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);                        
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }

    lblinThree.setVisible(false);
    lblinTwo.setVisible(true);

    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);                        
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }

    lblinTwo.setVisible(false);
    lblinOne.setVisible(true);

    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);                        
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }

    lblinOne.setVisible(false);          
  }
}
}  
}
```

after some Seconds it would Print everything in just one Line.

[image]

Please help me fix this issue. Thank You.

Comment: You are freezing the whole thread. You should consider creating a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and edit your labels on each tick.

Comment: like How Do i do it. I looked at the API for it and followed the exact same thing but it still gave me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole program runs one one thread (unless you create or the program creates any  threads). So to run something separately on its own thread you do something like the following:

```
if (event.getSource() == b) {
Thread th=new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    b.setText("1");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);                        
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
    b.setText("2");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);                        
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
    b.setText("3");   
  }
};
th.start();
}
```

Inside the run() method you put what you want to execute.